# How to limit the storage size of an Individual MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, relational-database, storage

I want to be able to place limits on the storage size an individual MySQL database (for example 2GB per database). Was this able to be done? I'm unable to a find specific MySQL configuration that allows this.

Specifically I want to be able to do this on AWS RDS Instance - so any knowledge related to this would be helpful too.

Any help or guidance wether this could be done would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting question. I found this link which shows some promise, but didn't test it myself: https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/limit-mysql-database-size.1944/  ... All the other documentation I found said that the size limits are based on file size limits on the host computer/server, so I suppose you could theoretically achieve the desire results with partitioning the host and limiting the allocated disk space to each partition. (Don't ask me how, been too long since I did that; just one potential approach).

Answer (score 3):

This question was asked almost 10 years ago: [MySQL schema size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561612/mysql-schema-size)

I won't close your question as a duplicate because it has been long enough that it deserves a fresh answer.

Nothing has changed. There is no option for MySQL to define a cap on the size of an individual database.

You can make a max size for the system tablespace, and all your tables and schemas will fill this if you set `innodb_file_per_table=0`. You can configure the max size in your my.cnf this way:

```
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:12M:autoextend:max:1G
```

That's just an example, it means the ibdata1 file is initially created at 12MB, it grows as needed, but will not grow larger than 1GB. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-init-startup-configuration.html for more information.

Even with the potential limit on the system tablespace, this doesn't give you control over how much space each schema can use. They all use the same tablespace.

If you use `innodb_file_per_table=1`, each table is stored in its own tablespace file. There is no option for defining the size of a table-specific tablespace.

Since MySQL 5.7, you can also create a [General Tablespace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/general-tablespaces.html), and assign multiple tables to it. For example, you could choose to put all tables for a specific schema into one general tablespace. But this also has no syntax for defining a size limit of a general tablespace.

I've seen some solutions on the net to revoke insert/update privileges on a schema if it exceeds its size limit. But this is not enforced by MySQL, it's an external solution.